# Something wrong with this do carmo exercise (1.3.3)?

Tags: differential-geometry

I think I have found an unreported errata to this problem.

Here is my attempt to solve the problem.

[Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces - Chapter 1 Section 3 Exercise 3](http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.com/2016/03/differential-geometry-of-curves-and.html)

And [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~devinatz/docarmo_errata.pdf) is the errata I can found online.

In particular, I believe the errata should include $ \alpha'(t) = (0, 2a) $ when $ t \to \pm \infty $, not $ \alpha'(t) = (2a, 0) $

Can anyone confirm my finding? What should I do to get this included in the errata?

Comment: Anyone, please? It is an easy 50 points of reputation just to confirm I am correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure I am correct, not sure why there is nobody coming and confirm.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting. Did you find my mistake?

Comment: :( The downvote was rather meaningless without a constructive comment.

Answer (score 1):

I worked through this and I don't see any mistake. However, that errata is not even close to being complete. For example, page 26 #16 is wrong without assuming an initial curvature/torsion, and page 47 #6(c) should say $\kappa_\beta=\kappa_\alpha/(1+r\kappa_\alpha).$